# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 issues

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I've attempted using the upgrade manager to move from 14.04 to 16.04 with no success.
here's the short story...

first error message:

```
Could not install 'ca-certificates'
The upgrade will continue but the 'ca-certificates' package may not be in a working state. Please consider submitting a bug report about it.
```

and then this:

```
Could not install the upgrades
The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a).
```

not sure if the first issue contributed to the 2nd, but any ideas? Or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only *safe* way of upgrading is by using a [Live Ubuntu session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick). The installtion will give you the upgrade option when it's applicable.

Also I would suggest not using your old *Home* partition when upgrading. This is because some configuration files sitting may cause compatiblity issues with the new Ubuntu version.

Personally, I actually don't think upgrading while the system is mounted should have been possible.

Answer (score 0):

Before beginning, it's recommended to backup your system to avoid losing data if the upgrade gone wrong. You may want to read [official Ubuntu guide to backup the system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem). Run following command to upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the error fixed before doing an update. Try:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove ca-certificates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Hope this helps.